# Create device tree for CM from AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, cm

So my phone has no development for CM13 (soon 14), but there is quite some development regarding the AOSP 6/7 branch.

The device trees are very different, meaning that CM has a lot more files than the AOSP one.

So my question is if there is any easy way to be able to convert the AOSP device tree to a CM one?

CM(unmaintained): https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_sony_z3c
AOSP: https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/device-sony-aries

Thanks!